# 12 months lag in unbalanced panel data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a new 12 months lag variable of the Plasma_mean variable to my panel data. 
PLasma_mean data starts 12 months before the other observations, hence the NAs for the other variables in dataset head.

```
  ProdGrp timeperiod Plasma_mean Mark.Invest_mean Reps_mean repcost_mean Sales_sum     Pcs_vol_sum
  1:               1/1/2003      948881               NA        NA           NA        NA              NA
  2:               2/1/2003      787974               NA        NA           NA        NA          NA
  3:               3/1/2003      872733               NA        NA           NA        NA          NA
  4:               4/1/2003      932405               NA        NA           NA        NA          NA
  5:               5/1/2003      922127               NA        NA           NA        NA          NA
 ---                                                                                                 
155: Product A   4/1/2010     1325862         36362.49      1.33     14436.66  168874.9             718
156: Product B  5/1/2010     1253672         53821.38      8.17     14336.67 1989798.9        4549
157: Product A  5/1/2010     1253672         37146.27      1.33     14436.66  152519.5         596
158: Product B   6/1/2010     1334744         69749.48      8.17     14336.67 1978877.4        4612
159: Product A    6/1/2010     1334744         38093.63      1.33     14436.66  164404.0         689

 gProt_vol_sum pckg_price_mean g_Prot_price_mean TotalpharmaBiosales_mean      dollarized_reps_mean      dates
  1:            NA              NA                NA                       NA                   NA 2003-01-01
  2:            NA              NA                NA                       NA                   NA 2003-02-01
  3:            NA              NA                NA                       NA                   NA 2003-03-01
  4:            NA              NA                NA                       NA                   NA 2003-04-01
  5:            NA              NA                NA                       NA                   NA 2003-05-01
 ---                                                                                                         
   155:        2378.5        191.0250          76.88328                  6023500             19200.76 2010-04-01
   156:       40109.5        288.6149          49.80379                  6135394            30.59 2010-05-01
   157:        2204.0        187.4431          76.11616                  6135394             19200.76 2010-05-01
   158:       41776.0        298.1715          55.74162                  8673498            117130.59 2010-06-01
   159:        2305.5        190.6980          76.77850                  8673498             19200.76 2010-06-01
             plasma_lagged
      1:            NA
      2:            NA
      3:            NA
      4:            NA
      5:            NA
     ---              
    155:            NA
    156:            NA
    157:            NA
    158:            NA
    159:            NA
```

Using the data.frame package, I did :

```
lag <- function(Plasma_mean, n = 12L, along_with){
+ index <- match(along_with - n, along_with, incomparable = NA)
+ out <- Plasma_mean[index]
+ attributes(out) <- attributes(Plasma_mean)
+ out
+ }
```

and then attached it to my dataset by product group

```
DT[, plasma_lagged := lag(Plasma_mean, 12, along_with = dates), by = ProdGrp]
```

And I got the plasma_lagged variable in the last column of my dataset. But it seems to carry no data. (looking at the observations 155 and on).

Any hint on how to fix this would be great.

H

Comment: What debugging have you done? Does your `lag` function work on a subset of your data for a single `ProdGrp`?

Answer (score 0):

You are lagging over 12 days, not 12 months. Try

```
library(lubridate)
DT[, plasma_lagged := lag(Plasma_mean, months(12), along_with = dates), by = ProdGrp]
```

(and please give the code for a reproductible example, otherwise I can't make sure this works).